# macOS Ventura - problem with WiFi and an external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I am stuck with WiFi-connection problem after a Ventura update. I am using an external monitor [LG 34GN850-B.AED](https://www.lg.com/hk_en/monitor/lg-34GN850-B), connected using DisplayPort.

With previous ISO everything worked pretty well. Now,  when I connect my MacBook Air 2022(M2 proc.) to my monitor, the WiFi drops. It does not turn off on its own, the connection is just unstable. It’s like the cable blocks WiFi signal. I want to point out, that when I use my Mac without the monitor - WiFi speed and bandwidth is perfect.

I wrapped my cable by metal foil. This helped, but of course looks pretty strange and not very safe. Is anyone familiar with this type of problem and know of a fix?

Comment: It sounds like the cable you are using isn’t shielded.  If it’s a basic generic cable, it’s the manufacturer didn’t use shielding to lower costs.  Try getting a new cable from a reputable brand like Belkin, Cables2Go, or Anker.  they are more expensive, but there is a reason for it.

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B08KS3CG94?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1 - I use this one. The problem is that I want to use 144 hz.

Comment: They are no longer available.  This is a red flag for me.  Try this one: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Belkin-DisplayPort-resolutions-3840x2160-B2B103-06-BLK-black/dp/B07XBZLKSD/ref=sr_1_2?crid=2RAR9M3KI1TJO&keywords=kin-displayport&qid=1674569136&s=industrial&sprefix=belkin+displayport%2Cindustrial%2C224&sr=1-2

Comment: So this cable now is very bad? Due to the update? My Monitor is ultra wide and 144 hz. Will it possible to use 144 hz with this cable?

Comment: When a seeming good product is suddenly unavailable, it usually points to an shady seller.  Ever since I started sticking with reputable brands, all the weird issues disappeared.  If the cable was “updated” they could revise the listing. .

Comment: I am completely agree with you. In spite of it one thing is not abundantly clear, - will it work with 144 hz frequency monitor? I mean, exactly this cable by belkin. Thank you)

Comment: It should, but check with Belkin to be 100§% certain. (Another reason for reputable brands - they have support departments you can reach)

Comment: okey, thank you)

Comment: If the new cable fixes your issue, be sure to report back and write an answer!

Comment: I bought cable by Belkin. For 1.5+- month everything looked fine, now the problem CAME BACK)

Comment: There might be something else.  Move your Air away from everything and make sure it works properly.  Then start adding stuff back one at a time to see what could be causing interference

Comment: I have noticed, that at some parts of my house Wifi works properly, but not always. Sometimes at this place everything goes fine, sometimes Wifi starts randomly disconnecting. I also want to point out, that the Wifi-rounter is situated on the 1st floor, while me is on the second one. On my other Apple-devices everything goes well, of course WI-FI connection doesn't have a high speed, nevertheless it is stable. So, pretty confusing thing)

Comment: Terminating AWDL-services helped a little bit with the internet stability and speed, problem, but hasn't completely solved it.

Comment: I never  see how killing AWDL would.  It uses the same antenna and radio assembly (transceiver) as your WiFi. This action is touted by many purporting to fix the issue, but it ultimately doesn’t.

Comment: If you have WiFi issues in the house as you described, get an additional access point like a [Ubiquiti](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257475/119271). I’ve standardized on these for work and home and I have zero issues with WiFi on any device, including all my Apple devices.

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my question for people, who has also encountered with this kind of problem.

I am not sure that the special kind of cable is quilty (only if it is poor-quality cable for 4-5 dollars), because I have bought a new one by Belkin (I think there's no need to hesitate about its quality) and plugged it. It fixed my issue for approximately one month, but yesterday the problem has popped out one more time!

Just try to turn off AWDL-service (this is AirDrop, CarPlay and so on) by using command sudo ifconfig awdl0 down. If you need to turn in on - use sudo ifconfig awdl0 up. It helped me and the quality of internet connecting has become better (and it no longer suddenly falls off). Unfortunately it will terminate some functions. If these ones are vitally important for you, then you have to look for another solutions.

In my opinion, it is not a hardware problem, more likely software issue after macOS Ventura has been released. So, also I would like to recommend regularly update your macOS and probably it will bear fruits and Apple will manage to solve this disgusting issue.

If you have any cleaning-programs, such as Clean MyMac of something like that, try to reset DNS-cache and just run a service script.